# Compare Multiple Values SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I am creating the 2 temporary tables below. I need to create a flag that says whether all of the weekly_sales values are less than the single average in Table 1, for each customer.  What is the best way of doing this?

As an example, here is table 1:

```
Table 1 
cust_nbr  avg_sales
1234      200
```

And here is table 2:

```
Table 2     
cust_nbr weekly_sales week
1234     222          1
1234     211          2
1234     121          4
```

Comment: Are you talking about one flag per customer which tells you whether all of their sales are below average, or one flag per customer per week which tells you whether that week's sales are below goal?

Comment: One flag per customer. 1 if all of the weekly_sales are below the average, and 0 if not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: it should select each customer, and flag them if their maximum weekly sales figure is still below the average set for them in `Table1`.

```
SELECT 
    A.Cust_nbr,
    A.Avg_Sales,
    CASE WHEN B.MaxSale < A.Avg_Sales THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsAlwaysBelowAverage
FROM 
    Table1 A
     LEFT JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            Cust_Nbr,
            MAX(Weekly_Sales) AS MaxSale
        FROM Table2 
      ) B ON 
        A.Cust_Nbr = B.Cust_Nbr
```

Answer (score 1):

To get whether any single value is greater than all of the weekly_sales values, you can do something like this.

```
CASE 
    WHEN @avg > (
        SELECT MAX(weeky_sales)
            FROM [Table 2]
        ) THEN
        1
    ELSE
        0
END
```

If you incorporate that into a function, you can add a computed column on `[Table 1]` to call the function based on the `avg_sales`.